# Advanced Item Instance management trouble

Tags: java

I've been developing a massive Role Playing Game. The problem is that I'm having trouble engineering how will I manage the Item and Inventory system. Currently I have something similar to this:

- public abstract class Item has 5 Nested classes which all are abstract and static that represent the types of Items. Every Nested class has an unique use(), delete() (Which finalizes the class instance) and sell()(triggers delete) void. They also have optional getter and setter methods, like the setAll() method which fills all necesary fields.
- Default: Has base price, tradeability boolean, String name, etc... Very flexible
- Weapon: Else than the things that the Default type has, it has integers for stat bonus on being equipped(used in the equip() and unequip() voids). Interacts with public class Hero.
- Equipment: Similar to Weapon, just that it has an Enum field called 'EquipSlot' that determines where it is equipped.
- Consumable: Similar to default, just that has a consume() void that enables the player to apply certain effects to an Hero when using it. Consuming usually means triggering the delete() void.
- Special: Usually quest related items where the 'Tradeable' boolean is *static, final and always false*.

Now, the way that I make customized items is this.

- First, I make a new class (Not abstract)
- Then, I make it extend Item.ItemType
- Then, I make a constructor which has the setAll(info) void inside.
- Then, I can use this class in other classes.

It all looks like this:

```
package com.ep1ccraft.Classes.Items.Defaults;

import com.ep1ccraft.apis.Item.*;

public class ItemExample extends Item.Default {
    public ItemExample() { // Constructor
        this.setAll(lots of arguments here);
    }
}
```

then I can do:

```
ItemExample something = new ItemExample();
```

And I have a perfect ItemExample with all the properties that I want, So, I can make various instances of it, and use amazing methods like 'getName()' and that kind of stuff.

The problems come to Naming the instances, as I do not know how to make an automated form that will give the instance a Different name from the other instance so they don't collide. Also, I want to implement an inventory system that uses slots as containers and can keep stacks (Stackable items only), also the main feature of it is that you can drag and drop them into other slots (For example, to reorganize or to move to another inventory instance like a bank, or to place in an hero's weapon or equipment slots, if it is allowed) and that you can click on them to display a screen that shows the name, description and possible actions of the Item (Which trigger the previously mentioned delete() and use() voids).

Thank you for reading all that! I know that maybe I'm asking for too much, but I'll appreciate any answers anyway!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.  Are you looking for a way to generate unique names?  If so, what are your criteria?  Do they have to be human-readable names, or IDs?  If the latter, you could use a UUID generator.  If the former, making them unique is a challenge.

Comment: Do you need a unique name, or just a way to differentiate items in the engine.

Comment: They can be IDs without giving problems. I just need each instance to have different names and to be accesible when clicked inside the Inventory user interface. Also, each instance has an Iconic image that is declared in a variable. That is what is displayed in the Inventory user interface.

Comment: Each instance has a human friendly name string that is displayed so an ID identifier would be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, you're asking for a unique identifier for your object. There are probably countless approaches to this, but the three different approaches that immediately come to mind are:

**1: A UUID; something like:**

```
java.util.UUID.randomUUID()
```

*Pros*: A very, very simple solution...

*Cons*: It does generate a large amount of bytes (16 + the object itself), taking memory / disk storage, which might be an issue in a MMO

**2: A global running number; something like:**

```
class ID {
    private static volatile long id = 0;
    public synchronized long nextId() {
        return id++;
    }
}
```

*Pros*: Again, a simple solution...

*Cons*: Even though this is a very simple class, it does contain "volatile" and  "synchronized", which might be an issue for an MMO, especially if it is used heavily. Also, What happens after X years of running time, if you run out of numbers. A 64 bit long does require quite a lot of named objects to be created, it may not be an issue after all... you'll have to do the math yourself.

**3: Named global running numbers; something like:**

```
class NamedID {
    private static volatile Map<String, Long> idMap = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    public synchronized long nextId(String name) {
        Long id = idMap.get(name);
        if (id == null) {
            id = 0;
        } else {
            id++;
        }
        idMap.put(name, id);
        return id;
    }
}
```

*Pros*: You get id's "localized" to whatever name you're using for it.

*Cons*: A bit more complex solution, and worse than "2" in terms of speed, since the synchronzation lasts longer.

Note: I couldn't figure out how to make this last suggestion faster; i thought of using a `ConcurrentHashMap`, but that won't work since it works on a lower level; i.e. it will not guarantee that two thread does not interfere with each other between the `idMap.get` and the  `idMap.put` statements.